# Adding scrollbar to Racket GUI

Tags: scheme, scrollbar, racket

I have a frame object where many text-fields and messages are added one by one.

```
(define myframe (new frame% [label "myframe"]))
(new message% [label "message1"] [parent myframe])
(new text-field% [label "tf1"] [parent myframe])
...
```

Hence, the frame has gone beyond the screen in vertical direction but no scrollbar has appeared.

I believe init-auto-scrollbars is only canvas%. 
How can I add a scrollbar to see all GUI elements on a frame object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a frame, add a panel to the frame.
Then add your gui elements to the panel.

Panels supports scrollbars:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/panel_.html?q=frame%25

Comment: I tried but elements are not adding up on panel as cleanly as they are on frame. Any particular change do I need to make in other settings?

Comment: Use a`horizontal-panel%` or a `vertical-panel%` instead.

Comment: Yes, that is much better.

Comment: How do I move up and down with keyboard here (UP DN or PGUP PGDN keys)?

Comment: Use `on-subwindow-char` to get key events. See http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/window___.html?q=panel%25#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._window~3c~25~3e%29._on-subwindow-char%29%29

Comment: Can you write a brief example code for this. I am not able to find one on websearch.

Comment: No time. Lots of examples at Github: https://github.com/search?q=language%3Aracket+on-subwindow-char&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Note: According to the [docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/vertical-panel_.html) `vertical-panel%` does not support the `style` values for scrolling. Although it is a subclass of `panel%`, it seems it did not inherit the abilities of scrolling. To me it is unclear, if this answer suggests wrapping a vertical panel into a panel or using only a vertical panel instead, which does not seem to work.